# Particle が to indicate place?

Tags: grammar, song-lyrics

I am currently confused with this:

> あぁ 花火が夜空 きれいに咲いて ちょっとセツナク

Google translate translate this part:

> 花火が夜空

as "Fireworks in the night sky". So, is that mean particle がcan be used to indicate location? If it so, is there any reference so I can understand it better?

However, can I say "Fireworks in the night sky" in Japanese like this:

> 夜空に花火

Thank you.

Comment: Please add more context. What is the full sentence? Or the sentences before and after. It could just be a shortened version of something like 花火が夜空を彩る. Some more info would help.

Comment: @kandyman I have edited the post to give better context. Please help me :)

Comment: Isn't this が just marking the subject of 咲く?

Comment: The line is from song lyrics, right? Grammatically I think it should be 花火が夜空**に** きれいに咲いて... but they wanted to make it 7 mora long, maybe??

Comment: You've got not only the assumption of the meaning wrong, but also seem to be confused how particles work in Japanese. If が was to indicate location, it would be "night sky (located) in the fireworks".

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a poem to me. Apart from the あぁ at the start, it's in a 7-7-7 moraic configuration, which suggests the writer is adhering to a particular scheme. If this is a poem, the usual rules of grammar don't apply. There are a lot of ways in which poets 'bend the rules' of grammar in order to keep to the standardized form. So I wouldn't be too worried if something looks a little out of place sometimes.

Having said that, the が here is just pointing out the subject of a verb, which is 花火. The verb is 咲く, ie 花火が咲く. However, it's also possible that another verb is omitted in the first phrase, like the 花火が夜空を彩る I mentioned in my comment. Then 咲く is used again with 花火 still as the subject.

In either case, the が is just the normal subject marker.